# Perl regex non-greedy matching

Tags: regex, perl

I am piping `ls` into Perl looking for lines that contain some any characters followed by ".mp4.mp3" at the end of the line. I want to remove the ".mp4" from the middle of the line. Here is my command:

```
ls | perl -pe 's|(.+?)\.mp4\.mp3$|\1\.mp3|'
```

I am using non-greedy matching so the regex will stop consuming the line when it runs into ".mp4.mp3". I would expect this to only operate on lines that end in ".mp4.mp3", but it is operating on lines without ".mp4" in them at all.

Input: foo . bar.mp4.mp3

Expected output: foo . bar.mp3

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just replace `.mp4.mp3` with `.mp3`?

Comment: show sample input and expected and actual output

Comment: you should always enable warnings, even on oneliners.  it isn't an actual problem here, but using \1 instead of $1 on the right side of a substitution is an error.

Comment: since what follows is a fixed string up to the end of the line, your non-greedy matching won't have any effect on the results, and a trivial at best effect on the time it takes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by 'operating on lines without ".mp4" in them at all' you mean you only want to print out filenames that the substitution changes, you need to not use -p and explicitly print the ones you want:

```
ls | perl -wne'print if s/\.mp4\.mp3$/.mp3/'
```

Comment: I was attempting to eventually pipe this into xargs -n2 mv, like I usually do with sed (but sed doesn't support non-greedy, which I don't really need) but I see that -p prints every line unlike the sed p which prints the lines where the replace happens. I see that perl can operate on files in place with -i, but how would I use this here?

Comment: Does my answer not work for you?  You can do in place  editing too, but that doesn't really help if you want to use xargs.

Comment: wait, are you trying to print both the old and new names so mv renames them?  then you want `print if s/^((.*)\.mp4\.mp3)$/$1\n$2.mp3/`.  or better yet, just use the rename command instead of perl.

Comment: Yeah, either inplace editing OR printing each line where the replace will happen followed by the replaced line for piping into xargs. I will go ahead and accept since I just asked for this first part though.

Comment: nice, yeah the comment is what I was looking for. I didn't think about being able to put a newline in there.

Comment: wait, no it doesn't seem to work when followed by "| xargs -n2 mv". Something about the whitespace or hypens are messing it up.

Comment: that's cool though, I will just strip the whitespace and hyphens from file names.

Comment: if you have whitepace in filenames, try `perl -wne'print if s/^((.*)\.mp4\.mp3)\n/$1\0$2.mp3\0/' | xargs -0 -n2 mv` .   I don't see how hyphens could be a problem, unless you have leading hyphens, in which case you need `mv --` instead of just mv.

Answer (score 1):

Don't overthink it :)

```
s/\.mp4\.mp3$/.mp3/
```

Rename the files in Perl:

```
ls | perl -lne '($newname = $_ ) =~ s/\.mp4\.mp3$/.mp3/; rename($_, $newname)'
```